# How to log in to a website using installed twill?

Tags: python, logging, twill

I have just successfully installed [**TWILL**](https://web.archive.org/web/20180904160747/http://twill.idyll.org:80/) on my computer with the help of one very supportive member of "StackOverflow" (you can check it out [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651334/how-can-i-start-using-twill)) and have tried to run one of the simple examples on the twill documentation page (you can see that page [**HERE**](https://web.archive.org/web/20180903115044/http://twill.idyll.org:80/examples.html)). Here is that example:

[image]
<sub>(source: [narod.ru](http://roundcan.narod.ru/some_pics/19.jpg))</sub>

Let's say my username on [www.slash.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20160307172942/http://slash.org/) is **lynxye** and my password is **mammal**. 
When I try to enter that example code into my Python prompt, I can only type and enter the first line of the code because when I click on "Enter" to start a new line, I get some error messages right away:

[image]
<sub>(source: [narod.ru](http://roundcan.narod.ru/some_pics/20.jpg))</sub>

The same happens when I try to enter this code into my terminal:

[image]
<sub>(source: [narod.ru](http://roundcan.narod.ru/some_pics/21.jpg))</sub>

I think I miss out on some basics here. Perhaps, I need to create a file that would contain that code and then run that file somehow, but I really don't know where I need to create that file and with what extensdion.

Can anyone, please, help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run those commands inside twill shell, instead of python shell

```
D:\tmp\twill-0.9>python twill-sh

 -= Welcome to twill! =-

current page:  *empty page*
>>
```

You can put twill commands when you see `>>`

or there is 2 only lines in twill-sh file

```
import twill.shell
twill.shell.main()
```

you can just copy paste that 2 lines to python prompt.

```
>>> import twill.shell
>>> twill.shell.main()

 -= Welcome to twill! =-

current page:  *empty page*
>> ?

Undocumented commands:
======================
add_auth             fa           info             save_html           title
add_extra_header     find         load_cookies     setglobal           url
agent                follow       notfind          setlocal
back                 formaction   redirect_error   show
clear_cookies        formclear    redirect_output  show_cookies
clear_extra_headers  formfile     reload           show_extra_headers
code                 formvalue    reset_browser    showforms
config               fv           reset_error      showhistory
debug                get_browser  reset_output     showlinks
echo                 getinput     run              sleep
exit                 getpassword  runfile          submit
extend_with          go           save_cookies     tidy_ok

current page:  *empty page*
>>
```

Comment: Hello, S.Mark!!! Do you know where that twill shell could be located? There is one file called "twill-sh" in my "twill-0.9" folder. Is that the twill shell? Strange, it's blank - I mean, it  has no extension.

Comment: Hi, yeah, run like `python twill-sh`

Comment: or just rename it to twill-sh.py :-) then you can do `twill-sh.py` in command prompt.

Answer (score 3):

This'll do it:

```
>>> import twill.commands
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> class browser:
...    def __init__(self, url="http://www.slashdot.org"):
...       self.a=twill.commands
...       self.a.config("readonly_controls_writeable", 1)
...       self.b = self.a.get_browser()
...       self.b.set_agent_string("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.8.1.14) Gecko/20080404 Firefox/2.0.0.14")
...       self.b.clear_cookies()
...       self.url=url
...    def slashdot(self, loginName, passwd):
...       self.b.go(self.url)
...       f = self.b.get_form("1")
...       regexp = re.compile("Log In")
...       link = self.b.find_link(regexp)
...       if link:
...          self.b.follow_link(link)
...          f=self.b.get_form("2")
...          f["unickname"] = loginName
...          f["upasswd"] = passwd 
...          self.a.fv("2", "userlogin", "") 
... 
>>> 
>>> t=browser()
>>> t.slashdot("username", "password")
==> at http://slashdot.org/
==> at http://slashdot.org/my/login
forcing read-only form field to writeable  
>>>
```

Its also easier if you use BeautifulSoup to parse the html

Comment: Thakn You, amadain!!! Can You, please, tell me, what does the second line of Your code (>>> import re) do?

Comment: import re - import the regular expression module. Are you not used to python? I would suggest running through the tutorial on www.python.org. It is a very good tutorial to get you started on python

Comment: Thank You, amadain!!! Yes, I am just a beginner in python. Thank You for referring me to that tutorial - a lot of my questions are explained there!

Answer (score 0):

The angle brackets aren't meant to be entered literally; they're just there to indicate you should enter a value.  Try

`setlocal username lynxye`

instead.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way to use in prompt.

You need to enclose key-value pair in brackets. Like,

setlocal('uname','xyz')

setlocal('password','123')

go('http://abc.org')

fv('1','foo','bar')