# Using Twill from Python to open a link: " 'module' object has no attribute 'Popen' " What is it?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, popen, twill

I have downloaded and installed **[Python 2.5.4](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5.4/)** on my computer (my OS is ***Windows XP***), downloaded **[“Goggle App Engine Software Development Kit”](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/downloads.html)** and created my first application in Python, which was a directory named ***helloworld*** that contained a small python file with the same name (***helloworld.py***). Here are the contents of that small file:

---

```
print 'Content-Type: text/plain'
print ''
print 'Hello, world!'
```

---

Whenever I ran this application locally on my computer with **[“Goggle App Engine Software Development Kit”](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/downloads.html)**, my browser (FireFox) always showed me a white window with ***Hello, world!*** written in it.

Then I downloaded **[Twill](http://twill.idyll.org/)** and unpacked it into ***helloworld*** directory. **[Having installed Twill properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651334/how-can-i-start-using-twill)**, I was able to execute some small commands from Twill shell. For example, I could turn to a web page by some link:

[image]

Then I wanted to perform the same operation directly from Python (i.e. by means of using Twill from Python.) Here is what the **[Twill documentation page says about it](http://twill.idyll.org/python-api.html)**:

---

**twill's Python API**

Using TwillBrowser Making extensions

twill is essentially a thin shell around the mechanize package. All twill commands are implemented in the commands.py file, and pyparsing does the work of parsing the input and converting it into Python commands (see parse.py). Interactive shell work and readline support is implemented via the cmd module (from the standard Python library).

**Using twill from Python**

There are two fairly simple ways to use twill from Python. (They are compatible with each other, so you don't need to choose between them; just use whichever is appropriate.)

The first is to simply import all of the commands in commands.py and use them directly from Python. For example,

```
from twill.commands import *
go("http://www.python.org/")
showforms()
```

This has the advantage of being very simple, as well as being tied directly to the documented set of commands in the commands reference.

---

So I decided to use this way. I deleted the previous contents of ***helloworld.py*** and gave it the new contents:

---

```
from twill.commands import *
go("http://www.python.org/")
showforms()
```

---

But when I tried to run that file on my computer with **[“Goggle App Engine Software Development Kit”](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/downloads.html)**, my browser, instead of depicting the contents of www.python.org web site, gives me an error message: ***'module' object has no attribute 'Popen'*** :

[image]

Please, take a look at the whole page **[here](http://roundcan.narod.ru/pop-open.html)**.

Here are the last three lines of that page:

---

: 'module' object has no attribute 'Popen'

```
  args = ("'module' object has no attribute 'Popen'",)

  message = "'module' object has no attribute 'Popen'"
```

---

Can anybody, please, explain to me what this Popen attribute is all about and what I am doing wrong here?

Thank you all in advance.

---

**Update 1**

(this update is my response to the second answer provided below by **leoluk**)

Hello, leoluk!!!

I tried doing it this way:

```
config use_tidy 0
from twill.commands import *
go("http://www.python.org/")
```

but it didn't work. I received this error message:

```
<type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'>: invalid syntax (helloworld.py, line 1)
      args = ('invalid syntax', (r'E:\helloworld\helloworld.py', 1, 15, 'config use_tidy 0\n'))
      filename = r'E:\helloworld\helloworld.py'
      lineno = 1
      message = ''
      msg = 'invalid syntax'
      offset = 15
      print_file_and_line = None
      text = 'config use_tidy 0\n'
```

(You can see the whole page **[HERE](http://roundcan.narod.ru/some_pages/tidy_config_problem.html)**)

Do You have any idea what it means and what went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The tidy program does a nice job of
> producing correct HTML from mangled,
> broken, eeevil Web pages. By default,
> twill will run pages through tidy
> before processing them. This is on by
> default because the Python libraries
> that parse HTML are very bad at
> dealing with incorrect HTML, and will
> often return incorrect results on
> "real world" Web pages.
>
> **To disable this feature, set config do_run_tidy 0.**

Comment: Hello, leoluk!!! Thank You for this input. I tried to set confing, but something went wrong. Perhaps, I didn't do it the right way. Please, refer to the "Update 1" (in the main body of my question on this page) to see the details. Thank You.

Comment: Hello, Wooble!!! Thanks for telling me that. After I read this comment, I tried doing it in this way: config('use_tidy', '0') and it worked!!! So, You were right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717325/how-to-combine-twill-and-python-into-one-code-that-could-be-run-on-google-app-en Twill CAN be included as a package into my python application to be run by "Google App Engine SDK" - at least I can do it locally on my computer! Thank You!!!

Comment: are you sure you want to disable tidy based on the info above?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use `mechanize` directly. Twill communicates with the system in a way that's not supported by Google App Engine.

```
import mechanize

browser = mechanize.Browser()

browser.open('http://www.python.org')

for f in browser.forms():
    print f # you'll have to extend it
```

Comment: Thank You, leoluk, for this code!!! But I just tried it and it said "No module named mechanize". Where can I get this module?

Comment: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/ (btw, this is the place you will get nearly all modules)

Comment: Thank You for this link, leoluk!!! I think now I should start studying how to use mechanize.

Answer (score 2):

you can't use anything in the Google App engine. Twill uses stuff not available on google app engine to work. So twill is not fully supported by app engine.

notably, the code is trying to call on an external command, `tidy`, and calling external commands in app engine doesn't work.

Comment: Hello, nosklo. Thanks for Your response. So what should I do now? I've spent so much time learning twill, because here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717325/how-to-combine-twill-and-python-into-one-code-that-could-be-run-on-google-app-en I was told that I just needed to include in on "GAP" with my application when deploying and it would all work fine. Now You are telling me totally the opposite thing. Can You, please, give me any clue as to what I could do?

Comment: Host it somewhere else -- GAP sucks in terms of support of external libraries. If you use another hosting service it should work.

Comment: Thank You, nosklo, for telling me this, but GAP is the only hosting service that I know of that can run my code round a clock absolutely free. Do you know of any other such hosting services?

Comment: @brilliant: I think paying for a host which doesn't restrict the code I can run is well worth it.

Comment: @nosklo. Hello, nosklo!!! I agree with you, but the problem is I am not an owner of any serious application that I would want to be run from some host. Especially, I don't have any business plan that could be carried out by running an application from a host and, thus, would return some of my expenses. All I am doing is just learning some programming by trial-and-error way, and I think it's not a sin to try doing it from a free host first.